# Error creating bean with name ‘hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory’ for example Spring MVC Hibernate MySQL Integration CRUD on netbean 8.1

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, model-view-controller, netbeans

I download solution and tray 2 tutorials using Netbeans 8.1 from
http://www.journaldev.com/3524/spring-hibernate-integration-example-tutorial-spring-4-hibernate-3-and-hibernate-4
and
http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial

SpringHibernateExample work fine
The second give me errors.
The only change that I made was adding dependency in pom.xml for
mysql-connector-java 5.1.9

I post same question and result on the original site. 
Thanks for any sugestion.
M Toma

the result:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name ‘hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory’ defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/NamedStoredProcedureQuery
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/NamedStoredProcedureQuery
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindDefaults(AnnotationBinder.java:276)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1402)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.68 (1.7.4) logs.
Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.68 (1.7.4)
```

After sugestion from v.ladynev
I did what you said (what I understood)
My pom.xml now is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.journaldev.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMVCHibernate</artifactId>
    <name>SpringMVCHibernate</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now my controler is:

```
package com.journaldev.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.journaldev.spring.model.Person;
import com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonService;
import java.net.URL;

@Controller
public class PersonController {

    private PersonService personService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "personService")
    public void setPersonService(PersonService ps) {
        URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResource(
                        "javax/persistence/Entity.class");
        System.out.println("  27 url=>>" + url);
        this.personService = ps;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPersons(Model model) {
        URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResource(
                        "javax/persistence/Entity.class");
        System.out.println("  36 url=>>" + url);
        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
        return "person";
    }

    //For add and update person both
    @RequestMapping(value = "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person p) {

        URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResource(
                        "javax/persistence/Entity.class");
        System.out.println("  46 url=>>" + url);

        if (p.getId() == 0) {
            //new person, add it
            this.personService.addPerson(p);
        } else {
            //existing person, call update
            this.personService.updatePerson(p);
        }

        return "redirect:/persons";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public String removePerson(@PathVariable("id") int id) {

        URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResource(
                        "javax/persistence/Entity.class");
        System.out.println("  69 url=>>" + url);
        this.personService.removePerson(id);
        return "redirect:/persons";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String editPerson(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResource(
                        "javax/persistence/Entity.class");
        System.out.println("  78 url=>>" + url);
        model.addAttribute("person", this.personService.getPersonById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
        return "person";
    }

}
```

Result: No any diference about what I get (HTTP Status 500)
No any sign of System.out.println result

more info:
warn and error from TomEE Plume

```
Search "(^WARN)|^(ERROR)" (7 hits in 1 file)
  C:\2016\IT\arh\01\02-fld\32-SpringMVCHibernate\02-TommEE-Plume.txt (7 hits)
    Line 6: WARNING: jar 'C:\2016\IT\nb\13\SpringMVCHibernate\target\SpringMVCHibernate\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar' contains offending class: javax.persistence.Entity. It will be ignored.
    Line 8: WARNING: jar 'C:\2016\IT\nb\13\SpringMVCHibernate\target\SpringMVCHibernate\WEB-INF\lib\javax.inject-1.jar' contains offending class: javax.inject.Inject. It will be ignored.
    Line 10: WARNING: jar 'C:\2016\IT\nb\13\SpringMVCHibernate\target\SpringMVCHibernate\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar' contains offending class: javax.transaction.Transaction. It will be ignored.
    Line 50: WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    Line 53: ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
    Line 149: WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    Line 152: ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
```

can I use that info somehow?

UPDATED
I try with Tomcat 8.0.32
Here is what I got:

```
13-Apr-2016 11:30:55.854 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\IT\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\conf\Catalina\localhost\SpringMVCHibernate.xml
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Apr 13 11:30:57 CDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 207 ms
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Wed Apr 13 11:30:57 CDT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/persons],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.PersonController.listPersons(org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/person/add],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.PersonController.addPerson(com.journaldev.spring.model.Person)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/remove/{id}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.PersonController.removePerson(int)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/edit/{id}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.PersonController.editPerson(int,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
INFO : org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
INFO : org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO : org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
INFO : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder - HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
INFO : org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
INFO : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 2093 ms
13-Apr-2016 11:30:59.502 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\IT\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\conf\Catalina\localhost\SpringMVCHibernate.xml has finished in 3,648 ms
13-Apr-2016 11:30:59.506 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SpringMVCHibernate]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCHibernate/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appSe
```

UPDATED
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.32

Update
I repet the steps:
1. unzip example from original site
2. open in netbeans
3. add mysql-connector-java
4. clean and build
5. deploy on Tomcat-8.0.32
now I got:

```
Search "(WARN)|(SEVERE)" (4 hits in 1 file)
  C:\2016\IT\arh\02\02-fld\03-SpringMVCHibernate\10-Tomcat-8.0.32.txt (4 hits)
    Line 3: 15-Apr-2016 08:02:31.980 WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-26] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [SpringMVCHibernate] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
    Line 4: 15-Apr-2016 08:02:31.981 WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-26] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [SpringMVCHibernate] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
    Line 9: 15-Apr-2016 08:02:31.981 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-26] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [SpringMVCHibernate] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap] (value [org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap@3aacedad]) and a value of type [java.util.Hashtable] (value [{}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
    Line 36: WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCHibernate/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

I dont know what to think about those.

Comment: What kind of an error? We are not telepaths!

Comment: original site is here [link](http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need this

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

because of you use a `SessionFactory`, not an `EntityManager`.

An annotation `javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery` resides in the
`hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar`. This library should be loaded by Maven as a dependecy of `hibernate-core-xxx.jar`. So firstly check this library in your class path.

if you have this library, the problem is with an old `hibernate-jpa-xxx.jar` (or similar) in the class path, because of an annotation `javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery` was added with `JPA 2.1` (an old jar is loaded before new one). And this jar can resides in the default Tomcat lib folder.

**Update**

It is a `TomEE` problem. It already has `hibernate-jpa-xxx.jar` (or similar with a `javax.persistence` package) that implements JPA 2.0 (or less). That implementation doesn't have `NamedStoredProcedureQuery`.

Looks like your `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar` was not loaded at all. Because of

`hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar' contains offending class: javax.persistence.Entity. It will be ignored.`

`TomEE` has `javax.persistence.Entity` in its old jar and ignores other jars contain it.

**How to fix**

1. You can try to replace an old jar with a `javax.persistence` package with new one (maybe you need to replace other jars too) in the `TomEE` folders.
2. Use `TomEE` with JPA 2.1 implementation (don't know it exists)
3. Use `Tomcat` or `Wildfly` of a new version.

Comment: I did what you said (what I understood).

Comment: I think my pom.xml is wrong. Netbeans have tool for graph for pom and so we can see how dependecy related to each others. [Free Graphs to Manage Maven Complexities](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/free_graphs_to_manage_maven) is about that graph.

Comment: @MToma You don't understand me with `System.out.println(url);`. You need  to comment or delete all xml parts related to  `hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory`, cause of Spring process it on a Tomcat startup. Before you can call any controller method! Maybe I propose you a wrong way. Try to check `hibernate-jpa-xxx.jar` for `NamedStoredProcedureQuery` inside. And try to find and delete all old Hibernate related jars.

Comment: Update about using Tomcat 8.0.32

Comment: @MToma Looks like, Hibernate was initialized without errors.

Comment: My example still not working - WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCHibernate/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Comment: @MToma You need to properly mapping `PersonController` to the `/SpringMVCHibernate` path.

Comment: As long I copied the project that was working my question how to detect what is wrong with mapping? Maybe there is a good place to read about that.

Comment: I posted a new question: spring, hibernate, MVC, how to detect what is wrong with mapping?

Comment: @MToma You need to check a mapping to the controller `/SpringMVCHibernate`.

Answer (score 0):

I Tray again the example in Netbeans and make it work.
I was wrong by expecting to see a page on url:
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCHibernate
If I change the url to:
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCHibernate/persons
I get an error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
...
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
```

I add the mysql-connector and I see tha right page;
Thanks for any comment